# injective module and injective cogenerator problem

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $E$ be an injective $R$-module. Suppose that for any proper left ideal $J$, there is some nonzero $x\in E$ with $Jx=0$. Prove that for any nonzero $R$-module $M$, we have $\text{Hom}_R(M,E)\ne 0$.

I know that if there exists $x\in E$ such that $Jx=0$ then $E$ is not torsion-free.
Since $E$ is injective module, then $\text{Hom}_R(-,E)$ is exact. So in other words, $E$ would be called injective generator since $E$ is injective and $\text{Hom}_R(M,E)\ne 0$. That's as far as  I could go. I don't know how to prove the statement.

Answer (score 2):

Take some nonzero $m\in M$ and consider the submodule $U:=Rm$ of $M$. Let $J$ be the kernel of $R\to U$, $1\mapsto m$. By assumption we have some nonzero $x\in E$ with $Jx=0$, so the map $R\to E$, $1\mapsto x$, induces a nonzero map $U\to E$. Finally, $E$ is injective, so this map lifts to a nonzero map $M\to E$.

Edit: here are some more details.

We have a nonzero $m\in M$, and the submodule $U:=Rm$. There is a surjection $\pi\colon R\to U$ sending $1\mapsto m$, and hence $r\mapsto rm$ for all $r\in R$.

We let $J$ be the kernel of $\pi$. This is a proper (but possibly zero) left ideal of $R$. By assumption there exists a nonzero $x\in E$ with $Jx=0$.

Consider the map $f\colon R\to E$ sending $1\mapsto x$, and so $r\mapsto rx$ for all $r\in R$. Now $J$ lies in the kernel of $f$, so $f$ induces a map from the quotient $U=R/J$, say $\bar f\colon U\to E$.

Finally, since $E$ is injective, the map $\mathrm{Hom}(M,E)\to\mathrm{Hom}(U,E)$ is onto, so $\bar f$ is the restriction to $U$ of some (necessarily nonzero) map $g\colon M\to E$.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have two questions: 1)how $J$ can be kernel of $R\rightarrow U$ from the definition $1\mapsto m$? and 2) how nonzero map $U\rightarrow E$ lifts to $M\rightarrow E$?

Comment: I think answer to question 2) is by Baer's criterion for injectivity. I just didn't understand how $R\rightarrow U$ and $R\rightarrow E$ induce $U\rightarrow E$.

Comment: 1) The map $R\to U$ sends $r$ to $rm$. Its kernel is a proper left ideal, which we call $J$.
2) Apply $\mathrm{Hom}(-,E)$ to the inclusion $U\leq M$. Since $E$ is injective, this gives a surjection $\mathrm{Hom}(M,E)\twoheadrightarrow\mathrm{Hom}(U,E)$, so we can lift every map $U\to E$ to a map $M\to E$.

Comment: So $M$ is not torsion-free since $J$ annihilates some element $m\in M$. But what if $M$ is torsion-free? I understand surjection part but how does $R\rightarrow E$ induce $U\rightarrow E$?

Comment: We have a morphism $R\to E$ sending the submodule $J$ to 0. It therefore induces a map from the cokernel $R/J=U$.

Comment: Just one question Andrew, is $f$ inducing map from $U$ to $E$ because of universal property of cokernels? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is usually proved along with the isomorphism theorems. We have $\pi\colon R\to U$ and define $\bar f(u):=f(r)$ for any $r$ such that $\pi(r)=u$. This is well-defined since $f$ vanishes on the kernel $J$ of $\pi$. This result can of course be interpreted as the universal property for cokernels.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. It makes perfect sense now!